# explode each array element if it contains comma

Tags: php

I have an array in following format

```
array(
       [0] => 1,2
       [1] => 3
       [2] => 4
       .
       .
     )
```

I want to convert this array into following format

```
array([0]=> 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4...)
```

What can can be the best to achieve this? I only want to split or explode array element which contain comma and append or create new array.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: You basically answered your own question: explode it when/if it contains a comma and put the values into a new array. Btw `[3] => 3 [4] => 4` is this what you really really want?

Comment: Yes thanks I understood now. I am new to php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about you implode your array and then explode it

```
print_r(explode(',',join(',',$array)));
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6774eeae1974d1daf10069b1e81a453700422b95)